# iOS what is the value of accessibilitySpeechIPANotation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, accessibility, avspeechsynthesizer

Based on this [WWDC2018 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/236/), we can dynamically change how words are pronounced in `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. 
[image]

I'm trying to do that in my Xamarin App, but I can't find the `accessibilitySpeechIPANotation` constant.

In the doc of `NSMutableAttributedString.AddAttribute(...)` it says that the constants can be found here: `UIKit.UIStringAttributeKey`. Yet the one I'm looking for isn't there.

**Does anyone know what the actual string value of the constant is? Or even better, where I can find in in Xamarin.iOS?**

(My app uses xamarin.ios v4.0.30319, if the constant is in a newer version of the framework, I'll update it, but google doesn't seem to give me any result when I search for it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**
Xamarin for iOS is based on Objective-C.And there are some differences between swift and Objective-C.

**Solution:**
The code is just like the following :

```cs
var attriStrng = new NSMutableAttributedString(new NSString("hello iPhone"));
// you can set the voice here ,a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡ is just for testing
attriStrng.AddAttribute(new NSString("AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute"), new NSString("ˈa͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡a͡͡.ˈfo͡ʊn"),new NSRange(6,6));

var voice = new AVSpeechUtterance(attriStrng);

AVSpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();
synthesizer.SpeakUtterance(voice);
```

Comment: Thank you... it works. Out of curiosity, where did you find the value of the constant?

Comment: @SimonCorcos I held `Command` while clicking `accessibilitySpeechIPANotation` inside Xcode. Then I pressed "Jump to Definition", which led me to its declaration inside UIKit

Comment: Here's what it says: "// Use an NSString, containing International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) symbols.        // Controls the pronunciation of a word or phrase, e.g. a proper name."